# Algorithm to transform a pixel array into a png?

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing

I have a generated pixel array as a Uint8ClampedArray and I want to transform it into a PNG image.

I can't use canvas to draw and get back the png, neither node-only libraries. Where can I find an algorithm for transforming pixel arrays into a png?

Comment: Where are you writing this code, and why can't you use canvas or node only libraries?

Comment: React Native & web. So it has to be portable since RN doesn't have canvas and web can't run node libraries

Comment: Have you tried looking into the source for libpng? Warning - it's would be a fantastically rough-ride. Just following along with the zlib decompression of the image data is hard enough. Doing it the other way? Ouch! Perhaps the files puff.c and puff.h in the zlib distribution would be of utility.

Comment: Following up on enhzflep's comment, maybe take a look at https://www.xarg.org/2010/03/generate-client-side-png-files-using-javascript/ which appears to be a limited port of libpng to javascript.

Comment: Works pretty well for 8bit png's. I just couldn't find anything regarding 24-bit pngs in the libpng website. I think there are come constants that are calculated for 8-bit only